# How to use parameter passed in Override method?

Tags: java, oop, methods, parameters, overriding

How can I use parameter passed in Override method?

For instance:

```
@Override
protected void updateButtonDayDate(Button dayButton,int currentMonth, int day) {
...
}
```

How can I use dayButton outside of the updateButtonDayDate() method?

Comment: Save a reference to it...but I'd be kind of terrified without more context

Comment: what you want to achieve here ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign it to global like this:

```
class YourClass {
private Button dayButton;

@Override
          protected void updateButtonDayDate(Button dayButton,int currentMonth, int day) {
this.dayButton=dayButton;
} 
}
```

Now you can use `dayButton` inside any non-static method

Comment: So at the time of execution the dayButton value should be same for both variables?

Answer (score 0):

You need to remember that this value will be null, before method execution, so either check for null, or wrap in Optional

```
  private Optional<Button> dayButton=Optional.empty();

    @Override
    protected void updateButtonDayDate(Button dayButton,int currentMonth, int day) {
        this.dayButton=ofNullable(dayButton);
        // rest of the method
    }
```

But this operation is worying, not clean:

- calling method twice will store only second value, so maybe a collection
- if it is ment to apply some action on all buttons passed to this method, but you don't know when operation will be executed, then a collection would be better for storing button references (look previous point)
- your approach **breaks single responsibility principal** of this method